# Prevent HTML Decoding on Form Values

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters, html-encode

I have a form element such as:
`<input type="text" value="O&rsquo;Reilly" />`

But when this form is submitted, the value passed to the form handler is decoded and the ’ character is sent instead of the original string `&rsquo;`

I need to get the original string in it's literal/raw form, but I cannot seem to force the page to stop decoding these HTML elements for me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML-encode the ampersand with `&amp;` to prevent it from being part of an escape sequence: `<input type="text" value="O&amp;rsquo;Reilly" />`

Comment: that doesn't help if the value is determined by the user. Seems rather odd that decoding happens when a form is submitted it should just send the value and do nothing to it.